# Cannot understand angular 6 error

Tags: angular, angular6

I am moving an existing project from angular 5 to angular 6 and I am stuck on this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Provider parse errors:
Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! ErrorHandler ("[ERROR ->]"): in NgModule 
AppModule in ./AppModule@-1:-1
```

I don't know how to determine the cyclic dependency.

Here it is AppModule

```
 @NgModule({
declarations: [
    AppComponent        
],
imports: [
    SharedModule,
    DialogModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot(allReducers),
    EffectsModule.forRoot([DossierEffects]),
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({
        maxAge: 5
    }),
    AppRoutingModule,
    DashboardModule        
],
providers: [
    {
        provide: ErrorHandler,
        useClass: GlobalErrorHandler
    },
    MessageService,
    UserService,
    DossierService,
    FavouriteService,
    SettingsService,
    ApplicationInfoService,
    StoreService,
    PermissionsService,
    DeadlineService
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
 })
 export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Would you be so kind and add your coding for app.module.ts?

Comment: please post app.module.ts

Comment: It's a quite large project, what I am looking for is a way to add more information on this error.. I will add an extract of app module anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cyclic dependency means that there is two services (providers) which has each other in their dependencies, for example let's say you have `Service1` and `Service2`:

service1.ts:

```
@Injectable({providedIn:'root'})
export class Service1 {
    constructor(private service2: Service2){}
}
```

service2.ts:

```
@Injectable({providedIn:'root'})
export class Service2 {
    constructor(private service1: Service1){}
}
```

So angular cannot create them, because it needs `Service1` instance to create `Service2` instance, but at the same time it needs `Service2` instance to create `Service1` instance.

It may be more complex in your case, but look for such kind of dependencies

Comment: I was using providedIn:'root' in service definition and at the same time defining the service in the providers of root module. Thanks for your reply